# Memory Leak with UIImage Pixels?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I've been working on some code which gets the pixels of an image, modifies them and then returns an image. When I run it in Instruments it says there are leaks on the lines of code that are marked with a ★. The following code just returns the original pixels without any modification:

```
CFDataRef CopyImagePixels(CGImageRef inImage) {
return CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage)); }

- (UIImage *) imagePixels:(UIImage*)imge {

CGImageRef img=imge.CGImage;
CFDataRef dataref=CopyImagePixels(img);
UInt8 *data=(UInt8 *)CFDataGetBytePtr(dataref);
int length=CFDataGetLength(dataref);

for (int i = 0; i < length; i+=4)
{
    UInt8 b_pixel = data[i];
    UInt8 g_pixel = data[i+1];
    UInt8 r_pixel = data[i+2];

    float outputRed = r_pixel;
    float outputGreen = g_pixel;
    float outputBlue = b_pixel;

    data[i] = outputBlue;
    data[i+1] = outputGreen;
    data[i+2] = outputRed;
}
CFDataRef newData=CFDataCreate(NULL,data,length);★
CGDataProviderRef provider=CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(newData);★
CGImageRef newImg=CGImageCreate(CGImageGetWidth(img),CGImageGetHeight(img),CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(img),★
                                CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(img),CGImageGetBytesPerRow(img),CGImageGetColorSpace(img),
                                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(img),provider,NULL,true,kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage*Result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImg];
CGImageRelease(newImg);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CFRelease(newData);
CFRelease(dataref);
return Result; }
```

I don't know why this is showing up. I've tried looking for an answer but none of them work.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**
The leak is coming from this method:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
ImageView.image = [oimage imagePixels:ImageView.image]; }
```

And oimage is set here:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
mainDelegate = (PhotoAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

CGSize size = mainDelegate.CurrentImage.size; 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( size );
[mainDelegate.CurrentImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width ,size.height )];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();//LEAK
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

int kMaxResolution = 300;
CGImageRef imgRef = newImage.CGImage;
CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {
    CGFloat ratio = width/height;
    if (ratio > 1) {
        bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
    }
    else {
        bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
        bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
    }
}

CGSize newsize = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newsize);
[newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newsize.width, newsize.height)];

newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
oimage = [newImage retain];
ImageView.image = oimage; }
```

Also, in the right side bar of Instruments, clicking on an object for a leak in the bottom central window will show you in the side bar where the link is coming from in your code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it possible that the UIImage you return is getting leaked somehow? Retained somewhere and getting lost and never going away? That would cause the underlying provider data to leak, but you'd think leaks would point out the leaked UIImage as well in that case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't leak, so here are some scenarios.

- The leak is elsewhere, you are interpreting the results of Leaks incorrectly.
- There is no leak, you are interpreting the results of Leaks incorrectly.
- Leaks is wrong (i haven't seen this, but maybe something about your code is confusing it)

When you say

> When I run it in Instruments it says
>   there are leaks on the lines of code…

What do you mean? As far as i know Leaks can't and doesn't tell you a specific line responsible for a leak, it gives you the history of a leaked object and you have to decide if you have over-retained the leaking object or under-released it.

If you only had one line in the object's allocation history (the creation of the object) then your problem would be under releasing, but none of the objects in your posted code would have a single-line history.

Maybe you can post a screenshot?

Comment: Hi,
I've edited the post and have added more info. I think that the leak may actually come from viewDidAppear? Also info for leaks is in post too.
Thanks for your help